# MVC Posting an Ajax call multiple times

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

i have a MVC project with partial views. Now i want to update the partial view with an AJAX call to the controller.

Javascript:

```
$('body').on("click", "#btn_add__row", function () {        
        $("#div_partial_view").load("/Subcodes/AddRow");       
        });
```

Controller action:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult AddRow()
        {            
            var model = GetFullModel();
            model.subCodes.Add(new DB.Models.AdministrationModel.PreissteuerungSubcodes { 
            Param1 = null,
            Param2 = null,
            ID = null,
            Param3 = null});
            return PartialView("~\\Views\\Administration\\_Subcodes.cshtml", model);
        }
```

...

The Form in the Partial View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Administration", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form_subcodes", name = "form_subcodes" }))
    { ... }
```

The "AddRow" action just adds an empty row to the table.

However, this is working only once because the side is not getting refreshed.
The submit form Button isnt working after that call as well.
But refreshing is not an option because i have states witch are supposed to stay as they are.

My Question now,
is there an other option to refresh a partial view without submitting an AJAX?
Or is there a posibility to send the post multiple times?

Comment: On the face of it it looks like repeated clicking will just set exactly the same returned HTML to the same div over and over. You need to modify your JS code so that it appends the returned HTML to the existing HTML, rather than repeatedly overwriting it.

Comment: The Code in the AddRow() is just placeholder at that time. My problem is that it doesnt even get triggered a second time.